# How to display "Google API directions" polylines with leaflet?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, leaflet

I would like to display an itinerary on a map with leaflet.

For this, I make a get request on the Google maps directions API. I get a json like this:

```
{
    "routes" : [
        {
            "bounds" : {
                "northeast" : {
                    "lat" : 51.5103406,
                    "lng" : -0.0627423
                },
                "southwest" : {
                    "lat" : 51.5049264,
                    "lng" : -0.0898856
                }
            },
            "copyrights" : "Données cartographiques ©2014 Google",
            "legs" : [
                {
                    "distance" : {
                        "text" : "3,0 km",
                        "value" : 2959
                    },
                    "duration" : {
                        "text" : "7 minutes",
                        "value" : 427
                    },
                    "end_address" : "29 Fowey Close, Londres E1W 2JP, Royaume-Uni",
                    "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 51.5064421,
                        "lng" : -0.0627423
                    },
                    "start_address" : "8 Southwark Street, Londres SE1 1TL, Royaume-Uni",
                    "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 51.5049264,
                        "lng" : -0.0898856
                    },
                    "steps" : [
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,6 km",
                                "value" : 601
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 77
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5099409,
                                "lng" : -0.0870841
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre la direction \u003cb\u003enord-est\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eBorough High St/A3\u003c/b\u003e vers \u003cb\u003eBedale St\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinuer de suivre A3\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eEntrée dans une section à péage\u003c/div\u003e",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "ypjyHxpPCG_@o@QY_AkAE?C?CCQSEGEEMQEEACGGIGeAo@]OA?ECQGGC_@KgHeBqAc@a@Iq@WYG_AUi@OIACAYG"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5049264,
                                "lng" : -0.0898856
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,2 km",
                                "value" : 152
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 25
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.50989,
                                "lng" : -0.0883307
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre légèrement \u003cb\u003eà gauche\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eArthur St\u003c/b\u003e",
                            "maneuver" : "turn-slight-left",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "cpkyHf_PGB_@EK?A?I@GFEHAJAJ?Z?V@NBRBPDVBFDHDLDFFFFFJFXL"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5099409,
                                "lng" : -0.0870841
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,6 km",
                                "value" : 590
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 72
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.50955829999999,
                                "lng" : -0.080139
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre \u003cb\u003eà gauche\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eUpper Thames St/A3211\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinuer de suivre A3211\u003c/div\u003e",
                            "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "yokyH`gPZ}DFu@Dg@H}@Bk@P_CRsDJuAJiB\\qE@QF_ABiA?i@CUCc@Ce@CWCMAIG_@Ke@Oa@ACQi@Qm@"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.50989,
                                "lng" : -0.0883307
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,5 km",
                                "value" : 498
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 73
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5093097,
                                "lng" : -0.0737046
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Continuer sur \u003cb\u003eByward St/A100\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinuer de suivre A100\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eSortie de section à péage dans 400&nbsp;m, au niveau de Minories/A1211\u003c/div\u003e",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "wmkyHzsNG[CWCUAS?E?c@?I?M@u@@I@_AFs@Jo@DYBM?G?C?C?K?QAs@A]AaACe@Ae@AQM{ASqAIc@CMa@{BEW?I?K?IBK@GHSHOHOJMHKLMRQVOPU"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.50955829999999,
                                "lng" : -0.080139
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,5 km",
                                "value" : 472
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 54
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5090739,
                                "lng" : -0.06770899999999999
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Continuer sur \u003cb\u003eMinories/A1203\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinuer de suivre A1203\u003c/div\u003e",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "elkyHrkMXc@XYHAJORg@VgAT}@Ry@Nq@FWDOD]B]?W?WASAWM_B]gDEe@Gi@i@uCo@uC"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5093097,
                                "lng" : -0.0737046
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,3 km",
                                "value" : 297
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 57
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5065805,
                                "lng" : -0.0666981
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre \u003cb\u003eà droite\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eVaughan Way\u003c/b\u003e",
                            "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "ujkyHdfL`Ak@VQZYZ_@JSJOJMFGJGJG@ALCHCPC~@?n@AL?`@?p@?\\F"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5090739,
                                "lng" : -0.06770899999999999
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "0,3 km",
                                "value" : 272
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 41
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5068938,
                                "lng" : -0.0629257
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre \u003cb\u003eà gauche\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eKennet St\u003c/b\u003e",
                            "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "c{jyHz_LASASAKCMM]Uo@ESGSAOAQ?SAwAFkB@c@FuCKcBAa@"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5065805,
                                "lng" : -0.0666981
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        },
                        {
                            "distance" : {
                                "text" : "77 m",
                                "value" : 77
                            },
                            "duration" : {
                                "text" : "1 minute",
                                "value" : 28
                            },
                            "end_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5064421,
                                "lng" : -0.0627423
                            },
                            "html_instructions" : "Prendre \u003cb\u003eà droite\u003c/b\u003e sur \u003cb\u003eFowey Close\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eVotre destination se trouvera sur la droite\u003c/div\u003e",
                            "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                            "polyline" : {
                                "points" : "a}jyHhhKrAANABA@C@G?ECEMG"
                            },
                            "start_location" : {
                                "lat" : 51.5068938,
                                "lng" : -0.0629257
                            },
                            "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                        }
                    ],
                    "via_waypoint" : []
                }
            ],
            "overview_polyline" : {
                "points" : "ypjyHxpPc@w@qAeBI?UW_@e@IKoAw@w@[g@OgHeBqAc@sAa@yA]qA[GB_@EM?QHGT?nAFd@H^Xf@RNXLZ}DL}ALiB|@sN^cFJiCC_AGiAQoAo@uBYiAGm@AgADmC\\kC?[EeDEkAOmBcA_GEa@?UDSRc@T]VYj@a@j@y@XYHAJORg@l@eCb@kBLg@H{@?o@Ck@k@gGMoAi@uCo@uCxA}@v@y@Vc@RUVOj@M~CAp@?\\FCg@EYc@mAMg@Ca@AkBHoCFuCKcBAa@rAARCBKCKMG"
            },
            "summary" : "A3",
            "warnings" : [],
            "waypoint_order" : []
        }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
};
```

I see there's some fields polyline with some weird data in it but I don't know what it represents. How can I display these?

Comment: You mean `polyline['points']`? I don't see the link between the question in the title and the question at the end.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, I would like to display the polyline representing the itinerary on the map with leaflet

Comment: Well I don't know about leaflet.js but from the doc, it seems that you can create a `polyline` which takes *an array of geographical points* http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline So you would basically need to get each `steps` coordinates from the response and pass it to leaflet `polyline`

Comment: Yeah, that what I did, but I though there was a more efficient way to do this using overview_polyline.points for example... Thanks !

Comment: If someone has info about this field content, I'd be happy to know!

Comment: the overview_polyline.points field is an encoded polyline. There are decoders http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/decode.html Although I am not sure about the legality of showing Google route polylines on a leaflet map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a Google maps encoded polyline.
You can use this library to decode them at the appropriate resolution:

[Polyline decoder (and encoder)](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded)

Basically they are an ascii encoded binary structure containing a set of polylines for multiple zoom levels.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use the Leaflet plugin: [Leaflet.encoded](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded) . That'll put the Google Encoded Polyline on the Leaflet map.

Comment: Even has an extension on L.Polygon: L.Polygon.fromEncoded(encoded [, options])

Answer (score 2):

The polyline data is encoded.  I had this same issue creating a rubygem to do more or less the same thing.   I came across a script written by a guy named George Lantz that decodes the string into points.  I have it included as ruby in my gem here.  You can probably figure out the logic in whatever language you prefer.

[Ruby Script to Decode GMaps Polyline Data](https://github.com/frugardc/directions/blob/master/lib/polyline_decoder.rb)